# Simple game programming in PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: cordova, graphics

I was wondering if I could make some simple graphical games using PhoneGap/Cordova. If its possible, can someone please direct me to the first steps?

Comment: If you intend on using the HTML5 Canvas, be aware that Android 4.4 doesn't accelerate it, and it has pretty lousy fps, and earlier versions had some serious graphical issues with canvas. Project Crosswalk might help: https://crosswalk-project.org. On iOS, however, it's possible to achieve very good results using Canvas.

Comment: thanks for the useful insights...
will keep that in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially when I was doing research on phonegap I came across a site that said there are many gaming app powered only bu javascript.So **yes,Its possible to create a gaming app** with  phonegap

So here are few link that you might find useful

http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/01/18/my-first-mobile-game-in-html-with-phonegap-build/

http://www.tricedesigns.com/2013/03/22/phonegap-legends-a-sample-game-app/

Comment: Glad the post helped...theres lot more of these type of apps...all the best

Comment: Phonegap is a broken and commercial branch of Cordova.